# Unread messages always NULL for Labels

Tags: php, gmail-api

I'm trying to get the unread messages count for each of my gmail labels but the response is always NULL for theses fields :

```
object(Google_Service_Gmail_Label)#2872 (14) {
  ["colorType":protected]=>
  string(31) "Google_Service_Gmail_LabelColor"
  ["colorDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["id"]=>
  string(5) "INBOX"
  ["labelListVisibility"]=>
  NULL
  ["messageListVisibility"]=>
  NULL
  ["messagesTotal"]=>
  NULL
  ["messagesUnread"]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "INBOX"
  ["threadsTotal"]=>
  NULL
  ["threadsUnread"]=>
  NULL
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "system"
  ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["modelData":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["processed":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I found this google bug report posted some years ago :
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759403

But i'm not sure it's the same problem.. Anyone have some more informations ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to have to agree that this looks like the same bug as you linked here  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759403

you should add your experience with this bug to the issue it's the best way too get it fixed.

personally I wonder if it has anything to do with system labels